# How do I write the correct request to output information to "get"? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, get-request

I immediately apologize for my English to you.
The fact is that I need to write a get request for my application with recipes. I want to make the request look like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id_recipe": 1,
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "name_ingredient": "Ingredient1",
          "counts": 30,
          "name_unit": "unit1"
        },
        {
          "name_ingredient": "Ingredient2 ",
          "counts": 1,
          "name_unit": "unit2 "
        },
        {
          "name_ingredient": "Ingredient3",
          "counts": 2,
          "name_unit": "unit1 "
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id_recipe": 2,
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "name_ingredient": "Ingredient2",
          "counts": 1,
          "name_unit": "unit3 "
        },
        {
          "name_ingredient": "Ingredient1",
          "counts": 400,
          "name_unit": "unit4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But it looks like this

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id_recipe": 1,
      "name_ingredient": "Ingredient1",
      "counts": 30,
      "name_unit": "unit1"
    },
    {
      "id_recipe": 1,
      "name_ingredient": "Ingredient2 ",
      "counts": 1,
      "name_unit": "unit2 "
    },
    {
      "id_recipe": 1,
      "name_ingredient": "Ingredient3",
      "counts": 2,
      "name_unit": "unit1 "
    },
    {
      "id_recipe": 2,
      "name_ingredient": "Ingredient2",
      "counts": 1,
      "name_unit": "unit3 "
    },
    {
      "id_recipe": 2,
      "name_ingredient": "Ingredient1",
      "counts": 400,
      "name_unit": "unit4"
    }
  ]
}
```

That is, it is necessary to somehow combine elements with the same id_recept into an array. But I do not know how!
Here's the code I'm using now:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID_RECIPE, INGREDIENTS.NAME_INGREDIENT, PRODUCTS.COUNTS, UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT.NAME_UNIT 
FROM PRODUCTS, INGREDIENTS, UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT 
WHERE PRODUCTS.ID_INGREDIENT = INGREDIENTS.ID_INGREDIENT 
AND PRODUCTS.ID_MEASUREMENT = UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT.ID_MEASUREMENT 
ORDER BY ID_RECIPE
```

This is how the table data looks like:
[table ingredients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp5Lr.png)

[table products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPgLN.png)

I use oracle.
I will be glad if you can help!

Comment: How is the JSON being generated? Are you using ORDS to select from the table and get that response using a GET REST API?

Comment: JSON is generated through a built-in service in Oracle called RESTful Data Service. I just wrote a request, created a template and inserted the code there for the get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gsalem was absolutely right. In my case it looks like this:

```
    select 'application/json', "JSON" from (SELECT JSON_OBJECT('items' value JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'idRecipe' VALUE R.ID_RECIPE,
        'nameRecipe' VALUE R.NAME_RECIPE,
        'urlImage' VALUE R.URL_IMAGE,
        'descriptionText' VALUE R.DESCRIPTION_TEXT,
        'timeCooking' VALUE R.TIME_COOKING,
        'category' VALUE (
            SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'idCategory' VALUE CAT.ID_CATEGORY,
                    'nameCategory' VALUE CAT.NAME_CATEGORY
                ) RETURNING CLOB
            ) FROM CATEGORIES CAT WHERE R.ID_CATEGORY = CAT.ID_CATEGORY
        ),
        'userInfo' VALUE (
            SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'idUser' VALUE U.ID_USER,
                    'nameUser' VALUE U.FULLNAME
                ) RETURNING CLOB
            ) FROM USERS U WHERE R.ID_USER = U.ID_USER
        ),
        'rating' VALUE R.RATING,
        'products' VALUE (
            SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'idIngredient' VALUE I.ID_INGREDIENT,
                    'nameImgredient' VALUE I.NAME_INGREDIENT,
                    'counts' VALUE P.COUNTS,
                    'measurement' VALUE (
                        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                            JSON_OBJECT(
                                'idMeasurement' VALUE M.ID_MEASUREMENT,
                                'nameMeasurement' VALUE M.NAME_UNIT
                            ) RETURNING CLOB
                        ) FROM UNITS_OF_MEASUREMENT M WHERE P.ID_MEASUREMENT = M.ID_MEASUREMENT
                    )
                ) RETURNING CLOB
            ) FROM PRODUCTS P, INGREDIENTS I WHERE P.ID_RECIPE = R.ID_RECIPE AND P.ID_INGREDIENT = I.ID_INGREDIENT
        ),
        'preparation' VALUE (
            SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'step' VALUE PR.STEP,
                    'urlImage' VALUE PR.URL_IMAGE,
                    'description' VALUE PR.DESCRIPTIONS
                )  RETURNING CLOB 
            ) FROM PREPARATION PR WHERE PR.ID_RECIPE = R.ID_RECIPE
        ) RETURNING CLOB
        ) ORDER BY ID_RECIPE RETURNING CLOB
    ) RETURNING CLOB
) AS "JSON" FROM RECIPES R)
```

I explain why **'application/json'** is needed. In the event that you want to use the **RESTful service** from oracle apex, in order to get a json file at the output, you need to add this to your code. Also select the **source type as "media resource"**. In this case, everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (as I don't have neither your ddl nor your data):

```
select json_object('table name' value table_name,'columns' value json_arrayagg(json_object('column name' value column_name, 'type' value data_type) returning clob pretty) returning clob pretty)
from dba_tab_columns
where table_name like 'DBA_HIST_SQL%'
group by table_name;
```

output is like this:

```
{
  "table name" : "DBA_HIST_SQLBIND",
  "columns" : [
  {"column name":"SNAP_ID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"CON_ID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"CON_DBID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"VALUE_ANYDATA","type":"ANYDATA"},
  {"column name":"VALUE_STRING","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"LAST_CAPTURED","type":"DATE"},
  {"column name":"WAS_CAPTURED","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"MAX_LENGTH","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"SCALE","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"PRECISION","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"CHARACTER_SID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"DATATYPE_STRING","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"DATATYPE","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"DUP_POSITION","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"POSITION","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"NAME","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"SQL_ID","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"INSTANCE_NUMBER","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"DBID","type":"NUMBER"}
]
}"
"{
  "table name" : "DBA_HIST_SQLCOMMAND_NAME",
  "columns" : [
  {"column name":"DBID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"CON_ID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"CON_DBID","type":"NUMBER"},
  {"column name":"COMMAND_NAME","type":"VARCHAR2"},
  {"column name":"COMMAND_TYPE","type":"NUMBER"}
]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works well! thank you!
But there is one problem. Uploading this code to RESTfull Data Service in Oracle, it doesn't work quite correctly. JSON is being generated, which does not look quite appropriate. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Here I'm generating a json_object. Probably for ORDS, you'll need to remove the JSON_OBJECT function.